# validate table row by prevent inserting duplicate data using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working in a form where i insert some data and added this data to table. Now i want to validate a column And this column should not be the same. 
[image]

For example i want to prevent inserting same project name in table row.
How it can be done in jQuery?

Here is my html code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 5px">
         <label>Project : </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" style="padding-top: 5px">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="project"
          id="project">
        </div>
       </div>
              <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4" style="padding-top: 5px">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success col-md-6"
         name="add" value="ADD" id="add">
       </div>
      </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div >
     <table class="table" id="showtable">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ACCOUNT HEAD</th>
       <th>DEBIT</th>
       <th>CREDIT</th>
       <th>CHEQUE</th>
       <th>PROJECT NAME</th>
       <th>MR.NO</th>
       <th>DEPT NAME</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code to check the column name is equal to input text.

add your column index  to: .eq(**column  index**)

Code Sample:

```
$('#showtable tbody tr').each(function () {
        $projectName = $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text();
        if ($projectName == $('#project').val()) {
            alert('ERROR')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. i think it will works for me . i have to write some code for verifying it will work or not.